# Python Pandas error: ImportError: cannot import name 'isna'

Tags: python, pandas

Full listing:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7dd3504c366f> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.tseries.api import *

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
       6 
       7 from pandas.core.algorithms import factorize, unique, value_counts
----> 8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, isnull, notna, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
     10 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper

ImportError: cannot import name 'isna'
```

This is obviously from the line:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Current version:

```
pandas==0.23.4
```

I have tried going back to version 0.22 and 0.19, but that didn't sort the problem.

Here is pip3 show pandas:

```
% pip3 show pandas

Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.4
 Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and                  statistics    
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by: pandas-datareader
```

Solved by both Mike Palmice and Reddi Mohan

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with both pip and pip3, but that didn't help.  I then used virtualenv and it worked.  Python3 and Pandas 0.23.4.  I have no idea why.  I thought they used the same when you first create the environment!!

Thanks, Mike and Reddi!

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? what happens when you install with pip install pandas? are you working in any sort of venv?

Comment: Not working in venv.  I have installed and uninstall to different versions and then back to the latest everything installs fine.  With earlier versions of Pandas, I get a different import error.

Comment: honestly i would submit a bug report to pandas on github. i bet they'll help you. in the meantime, you could try a) installing pandas to a venv and/or b) installing pandas to python2 or python3 (whichever one didn't cause the problem you posted about)

Comment: try these 2 things
- reinstall the package, I usually install using ```pip``` instead of ```pip3```, so try with pip install pandas
- Use virtual env or anaconda and install inside the env